# true and false null values in lisp vs scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

I want to use the function in a scheme program im writing however im unsure ho to translate the T & Nil values within the function. Can nil essentially be written as '() in scheme?

```
(define (listword (lambda (word)
  (cond
    ((isvowel (car word)) (novowel word))
    (T (novowel word NIL))))))
```

Comment: Notice that Scheme is _also_ a Lisp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're translating some Common Lisp code to Scheme. In Scheme, the `T` at the end of a `cond` expression can be replaced by `true`, but the idiomatic way is to use an `else`. And `NIL` is just the empty list `'()`, sometimes aliased as `null`.

Also, be careful with how you define a procedure, you wrote an incorrect opening parenthesis in the first line - the correct way is:

```
(define listword
  (lambda (word)
    ...))
```

Or equivalently (and perhaps more idiomatic):

```
(define (listword word)
  ...)
```

Answer (score 4):

To avoid confusion I'll take Common Lisp as an exemplar of a 'traditional' Lisp and call it 'Lisp' below, as opposed to Scheme: Scheme is also a Lisp of course but I want to have to type less.

Both Lisp and Scheme use the common convention that there is a single distinguished false object with everything else being true.  In the construction of lists, both Lisp and Scheme also need to have a special distinguished 'empty list' element which is also unique.  Lisp then chooses to pun, making the empty list and false be the same object: Scheme does not, and treats them as distinct.  Additionally, Lisp provides a *name* for the empty list object, while Scheme does not, and Scheme also does not treat the empty list object as self-evaluating while Lisp does.  Both languages provide a canonical true object as well, but again Lisp provides a name for it while Scheme doesn't.  In both languages the true and false objects are self-evaluating.

So.

(Common) Lisp:

- all objects are true except for the empty list, `()` -- `(if () 1 2)` evaluates to `2`;
- the empty list is self-evaluating -- `(eq '() ())` is true;
- the empty list is unique -- `(eq () ())` and `(eq () '())` are both true, as is `(eq () (cdr (list 1)))` for instance;
- the empty list has a name, `NIL` -- `(eq nil ())` & so on;
- there is a canonical true object whose name is `T` and whose value is `T`;
- while it is perhaps disputed, I think it is better to use `NIL` when you want to talk about false and `()` when you want to talk about the empty list.

Scheme:

- all objects are true except for the special false object which is `#f` -- `(if #f 1 2)` evaluates to `2` while `(if x 1 2)` evaluates to `1` for `x` having any value not `eq?` to `#f`;
- `#f` is self-evaluating --`(eq? #f '#f)` is true;
- `#f` is unique;
- `#f` has no special name in the sense that there is no symbol whose value it is (this is probably not the right terminology in Scheme);
- there is a canonical true object, `#t`, although all objects are true other than `#f`;
- there is a unique empty list object, `()` -- this object is not the same as `#f`, is not self-evaluating and does not have a name, so `(eq? #f '())` is false, but `(eq? '() '())` is true, as is `(eq? '() (cdr (list 1)))`, while `(if '() 1 2)` evaluates to `1` and `(eq? () 1)` is an error.

Disclaimer: my knowledge of CL is better than my knowledge of Scheme.

Answer (score 2):

In Common Lisp `nil`/`'nil`/`()`/`'()` represents the same value `nil` and it is both the empty list and the one false value. In Scheme they are two different values, `'()` for the empty list and `#f` as the false value. When translating Common Lisp one needs to determine if the value represents a false value or an empty list. In some cases you will have the empty list being used as a boolean and thus you would need to do `(not (null? v))` where CL just does `v`. The reason for this is that only `#f` is false in Scheme and thus the empty list is a true value. `(if '() #t #f) ; ==> #t`

In Common Lisp `t` can be replaced by `#t`, but in Scheme there are special symbols in some forms like `else` in `cond` that is the idiomatic way to do the alternative term.